# Foreach and Linq Statement Equalization

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

According to Resharper this two shall do the same:

1)

```
string strTemp = null;
foreach (var s in array)
{
    if (strTemp == null || !strTemp.Contains(s))
    {
        strTemp += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTemp) ? ";" : string.Empty) + s;
    }
}
```

2)

```
string strTemp = null;
foreach (var s in array.Where(s => strTemp == null || !strTemp.Contains(s)))
{
    strTemp += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTemp) ? ";" : string.Empty) + s;
}
```

How so? What am I missing?

Comment: The `if` statement has just been moved to a `Where` clause, so the loop is only acting on the filtered array.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: @DavidG strTemp is empty at point of where execution

Comment: I don't know what you are missing, but both code parts should do the same. What exactly isn't clear for you?

Comment: strTemp is empty at point of where execution isnt it?

Comment: filter shall be called on each loop but foreach only executes where onces. am i wrong?

Comment: Why do you think they'll be different?

Comment: Side note:string concatenation in a tight loop is not efficient. If there are more than few items in array, you need to use [StringBuilder](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by comments, you're expecting that this lambda expression will only be executed once, while `strTemp` still has a value of `null`.

```
s => strTemp == null || !strTemp.Contains(s)
```

That's not the case. It will execute for *each* element of the array, and will use the latest value of `strTemp` in each case. Even though the `Where` method is only called once, the lambda expression (or rather, the delegate created from it) will be executed for each element in `array`.

Your code would probably be better written as:

```
string joined = string.Join(";", array.Distinct());
```

... however. In particular, in your current code, if your array is `{ "ab", "a", "ab", "c" }` you'll end up with an output of just `ab;c` where I *suspect* you want `ab;a;c`... this is because `"a"` is already contained in "ab" by the second iteration of the loop. Of course if you *really* want that behaviour, the code you've got will work... but it does sound unusual to me.

EDIT: To understand all this, you need to understand how LINQ uses lazy evaluation. The `Where` method returns immediately without having executed the predicate *at all*... but when you ask the collection for its first element (via `GetEnumerator()` / `MoveNext()`) it will iterate over the array, testing the predicate against each item until it finds one which matches. It will then yield that item, and when you ask it for the *next* item, it will carry on from where it had got to, again testing the predicate against the remaining elements of the array.

It may be easiest to demonstrate this with a little code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var numbers = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        var filtered = numbers.Where(x => {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing {0}", x);
            return x % 2 == 0;
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Just before loop");
        foreach (var item in filtered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received {0}", item);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Just before loop
Testing 0
Received 0
Testing 1
Testing 2
Received 2
Testing 3
Testing 4
Received 4
Testing 5
Testing 6
Received 6
Testing 7
Testing 8
Received 8
Testing 9
```

As you can see:

- Nothing is printed from the predicate until we start iterating
- The output interleaves the testing with the handling of each included item

Comment: filter shall be called on each loop but foreach only executes where onces. am i wrong? strTemp is always null if foreach only executes where onces.

Comment: @devhedgehog: Read my answer more carefully. The `Where` method is only called once, but the lambda expression will be called for each element in the array.

Comment: where = lambda if lambda expression will be called for each element then result list will always be changed or not?

Comment: @devhedgehog: No, "where = lambda" is not correct. The Where method is only called once, but the iterator it returns will execute the lambda expression for each element in the array. Do you understand how LINQ uses lazy evaluation? It might be worth you reading http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot/ I'll edit my answer to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Version 2 refactors the `if`-condition from version 1 into the filter of the `Where` function call in the `foreach` statement.

Comment: filter shall be called on each loop but foreach only executes where onces. am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The if-block and the `.Where` method fullfill the same function.

In option 1 you iterate over the complete array and check if the variable matches the if statement.

In option 2 you apply a filter to the array which is equivalent to the if condition in option 1.

Then strTemp gets processed. The filtered data is identical in both cases, because the if-statement and the where clause are identical.